# unable to sftp get file with a python script

Tags: python

I need to get file and assign the contents to line array in python.

I am using psftp but I keep getting file error, I know that the file is in there:

Here is what I have:

```
import pysftp
myfile="daily_data_file_122300.csv"
sftp = pysftp.Connection('192.168.101.123', username='userid', password='userpassd')
sftp.cwd('userid')
sftp.get('myfile', preserve_mtime=True)

sftp.close()
```

I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

The file is there.

Comment: Are you sure about that `sftp.cwd('userid')` call? Normally the initial remote working directory of an SFTP session is the user's home directory, so it would appear to be unnecessary.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, if I take line out and do this: 
print(sftp.getcwd()), I get None printed.

Comment: According to the documentation, the return of `None` just means that you haven't explicitly set a working directory. It doesn't mean that the server side doesn't have a working directory. Anyway, what directory are you changing to and are you sure it's valid? Try an absolute path, e.g. `/home/userid`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, If I do sft.listdir(), I get file names like this: u'daily_data_file_122300.csv', dont know what u means?

Comment: `sftp.get(myfile, preserve_mtime=True)`; You used myfile as a string